# Support libraries must use the exact version specification error with compileSdkVersion 28

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-9.0-pie

After updating compileSdkVersion from 27 to 28 and updateing support libraries from 27.1.1 to 28.0.0 I got this warning message in Android Studio 3.2:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0` and
>   `com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0`

My Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    // Für Google "Mobile Vision" API
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'

    // wird nicht weiterentwickelt
    implementation 'com.edwardvanraak:MaterialBarcodeScanner:0.0.6-ALPHA'

    // für Butter Knife
    // https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'

    // Logging nur im Debug Modus
    // https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

    // Für Material Dialogs
    // https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'

    // Google support library
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'

    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

If I run the app, I received this error in the line **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);**

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
2018-09-26 15:03:49.987 21534-21534/com.timeshuttle.lagerapp I/zygote64:     at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
2018-09-26 15:03:49.987 21534-21534/com.timeshuttle.lagerapp I/zygote64:
```

How do I proceeed to resolve this problem?

When I add the line

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

the warning disappears, but the app still fails to start (same error message)

---

update

When I revert to 27.1.1, the version conflict warning does not appear. The warning only appears with 28.0.0. Should I reorder the dependecies?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your dependencies still using `com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0`, so you need either to update the dependency or use the older support library version.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Shouldn't there also appear the same version conflict warning when the 27.1.1 support library is used?

Comment: Yes, should be the same conflict. You need to use exactly the same version everywhere.

Comment: When I revert to 27.1.1, the version conflict warning does not appear. The warning only appears with 28.0.0.

Comment: That's strange, I had the same problem when combining 27.* and 26.* libs

Comment: The warning disappeared when I reordered the dependencies (moved the Android support library to the top of the list). However, app still crashes.